# to have confidence in sb

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-meaning

> If the people in inferior positions do not have confidence in those above them, government of the people is an impossibility.

I am logically weak, I wonder if this line suggests that the people in inferior positions having confidence in those in the superior positions, or the opposite?

Logically, it should be the ones in the superior positions must have trust in their subordinates, right? If the authors said:

> If the people in inferior positions do not have confidence **from** those above them

then I might have understood this line well. But right now, I think I just got confused with the preposition **in** here.

Comment: If a person has confidence **in** someone or something, that person trusts that person or thing. This is dictionary stuff.

Comment: Yeah, the line is a translation, from Chinese to English, and it’s different from the original Chinese line, that’s why I’m asking you. Everybody knows how to use a dictionary tho.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is cultural, but it seems very clear that in an organisation, confidence should go both ways.

The people at the bottom and the people at the top both have jobs to do.  The organisation will fail if either part fails, so the people at the bottom also need to trust that the people at the top are doing their job. Hence there is as much need for the people at the bottom to have confidence that the people at the top are trustworthy as there is need for the people at the top to have confidence in the people at the bottom.

In the context you give, it is about a relatively low advisor who quit because he didn't trust his boss.  The advisor didn't have confidence in his boss.